# Question Mark in URL Parameter when using two routes mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes, url-parameters

I have two routes, when I use the Default route it shows the url with Question mark in the parameter. I'm getting **Editar/id?3** -- instead **Editar/id/3**. The other route is working fine, could you give me some light. Thanks.

Global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "GaleriaCustom", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{categoria}/{subCategoria}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Galeria", action = "Index", categoria = "Noivinhos", subCategoria = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );           



    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Index.aspx -- wrong url **Editar/id?3** -- instead **Editar/id/3**

```
<a href="<%: Url.Action("Editar", new{ id = item.galeria_id }) %>"><img src="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/Img/Design/editar.png") %>" alt="Editar" title="Editar"/></a> 
<a href="<%: Url.Action("Detalhe", new { id=item.galeria_id }) %>"><img src="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/Img/Design/detalhe.png") %>" alt="Detalhe" title="Detalhe"/></a> 
<a href="<%: Url.Action("Excluir", new { id=item.galeria_id }) %>"><img src="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/Img/Design/delete.png") %>" alt="Excluir" title="Excluir"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first route is more greedy than the second and unless you use some constraints it will match all urls. Another possibility is to use the `RouteUrl` helper and specify the name of the route:

```
<%= Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { action = "Editar", id = item.galeria_id }) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it fixed the url on link , but link doesn't work more, I am having this issue now when I click(_The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Editar(Int32)' in 'TudoDeMassinha.Controllers.AdminGaleriaController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type_)